# Can't make a http request from Google Chrome console

Tags: javascript, http, request, google-chrome-console

Cannot make http request to my VPS server from Google Chrome console.

It is possible to send request to server from browser directly by simply going to http://11.11.111.11:5000/test (with proper IP address) and get right response. And all the requests also working in my React app with `await fetch('http://11.11.111.11:5000/test')`.

But if I try to make request from Chrome console, for example with fetch how it is shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248296/making-http-requests-using-chrome-developer-tools) answer, it doesn't work and gives me `net::ERR_TIMED_OUT` error.

Will appreciate if someone could gladly explain to me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What page are you on with the console open? From memory, you cannot make requests from the blank _"new tab"_ page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fetch() works in Extension but fails in Chrome Console/Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68163959/283366)

Answer (score -1):

It would have been much more helpful to see the complete error message, preferably with a reproducible sandbox or screenshots.

But to try to answer this, if it is failing,
then it must have to do with what service is deployed on that port.

I can see a few differences in headers between call made from browser url (left) and console fetch (right):
[Json diff comparing request headers from different points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrNs5.png)

The response from server may differ for both only if it is treating `accept`, `sec-fetch-dest` or `sec-fetch-mode` header differently.

This is the best I could come up with.